# Trouble running RMI application in Java

Tags: java, rmi

I am following this tutorial about Java RMI http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/TOC.html

However when I try to start the server I receive the following error:

ComputeEngine exception:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:61)

I am trying to run with the following command:

D:\files\develop\javarmi>java -cp D:\files\develop\javarmi;D:\files\webdocs\classes\compute.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/D:/files/webdocs/classes/compute.jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.162 -Djava.security.policy=server.policy engine.ComputeEngine

What should I do to correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

The server.policy file was wrong the correct is this:

grant {
permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-", "connect,accept";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: Not really. If you grant AllPermission you don't need the other one, and you don't need the file or the scurity manager at all unless you bare using the codebase feature, or you have a separate requirement for a security manager, in which case you certainly wouldn't be using AllPermission.